# Drawable resource file max dimension

Tags: android, drawable

I've created a single sprite sheet for my game app, with each frame 100x100 px.

Everything's been working well until after I added a few more rows to the sprite sheet, then suddenly nothing gets drawn onto the screen any more. I reverted the sprite sheet back to an earlier version, which had less rows, and everything works again.

The sprite that works is 400w*900h px, and the one that stopped working is 400w*1400h px... I suppose there's a middle ground somewhere I just haven't bothered to look for it.

My question is what is there a dimension limitation on the resource image files? And is there another way to get around what I just descripted other than splitting it into different files?

Thanks in advance

edit: getMaximumBitmapHeight() helped a little: On my testing device (nexus galaxy) it's only 2000 something... And on the emulator is in the 30k range :S Is there a way to set the allowed size? And if anyone knows... how different is it from phone to phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canvas class has a method [getMaximumBitmapHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getMaximumBitmapHeight%28%29) (& width , naturally ) to give you this  information for a given device, you can just print it in a log message.

On possible work-around is adding columns. Your image is only 400px wide but 1400 in height. It could be that 1400 is too wide but I very much doubt 400px is too wide.

Comment: Hmmm that seems to be the problem. On my testing device (a physical phone) it's only 2000 something... And on the emulator is in the 30k range :S Is there a way to set the allowed size? and if anyone knows... how different is it from phone to phone?

Comment: If it's 2000 on your phone that shouldn't be a problem if the bitmap is only 1400 tall , no? Since there is no corresponding set method I assume this is a physical limitation.

Comment: I'm gonna worry about dp vs px later... currently, it's 2:1 on the phone... I actually have to use 200x200 on screen even though each frame is 100x100 on file, so I guess that makes my 400x1400 file 800x2800, which is bigger than the max,  but... the limit is just too small... is it a memory issue? the file is only 17k... can I increase the max?